# How to find element by css selector for date field in Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble getting Selenium in Python to find a date field on a website. I am needing it to click 3 times in this box in order to highlight the existing value in that Start date field, and then send keys to enter in the specific date.

Inspecting Start date box gives :

```
<input type="text" mask="valDate" maxlength="10" 
size="12" id="f_2815055" value="4/1/2019" 
desc="Start Date" required="true" class="hasDatepicker">
```

I have tried doing

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".text[id='f_2815055']").click()
```

but I get the error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == .text[id='f_2815055']

I have also tried the same but with the class = 'hasDatePicker' and also desc = 'Start Date', but these all gave the same errors as above where it is unable to find the element with css selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and following `Css` Selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.hasDatepicker[desc='Start Date']")))
element.click()
```

---

### EDITED

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
for i in range(0,3):
 element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.hasDatepicker[desc='Start Date']")))
 element.click()
```

OR

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.hasDatepicker[desc='Start Date']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

Comment: KunduK, this worked, do you happen to know of a way to implement a triple click within this box? I am trying to make it to where it highlights the entire text field box.

Comment: @jwalls91 : check the Edited one if it helps to click 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use `find_element_by_id` since the element has an id that can be used to locate it:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('f_2815055').click()
```

Comment: I just gave that a try as well. Even though I tried driver.find_element_by_id, it gives the error message: Unable to find element with css selector == [id="f_2815055'"]